# How to show that $f(x)=\sin(x)+\cos(x)$ is sinusoidal(alternative)

Tags: trigonometry, alternative-proof

There was this question in our trig homework; it was for plotting a graph but I found it far more interesting than that. When drawing the graph of $\sin(x)+\cos(x)$ (by hand, which I find rather pointless), I found that it looked like some sort of sine or cosine graph. So I set out with all my trig identities to prove this.

$f(x)=\sin(x)+\cos(x)$

$\begin{align} f^2(x)=\sin^2 (x) + \cos^2 (x)+2\sin(x)\cos(x)&=1+\sin(2x) \\ &= 1+\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} -2x\right) \\&= 1+\cos\left(2x-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right) \\ &= 1+\cos\left(2\left(x-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) \right) \\ &= 1+2\cos^2 \left(x-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)-1 \\ &= 2\cos^2 \left(x-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) \end{align}$

So that means that $f(x)=\sqrt{2}\cos \left(x-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)$

Is there another shorter way to arrive at this result? Also, is there a geometric interpretation of this that can be explained to someone who doesn't know most of the identities I've used?

PS: If this question has already been asked please leave a link for it. I honestly tried to search for a similar question before asking this.

Comment: use the formula for $\cos(x-y)$ with $y=\dfrac\pi4$

Comment: Wow! Isn't that an answer already? Thanks. But is there a geometric interpretation or can one only hope in their trig formulas

Comment: Good on you for exploring and discovering trig identities on your own. It's not much of a step forward for the mathematical community, but it's a giant leap for a mathematician.

Comment: There is a flaw. From $a(x)^2=b(x)^2$, you can only conclude that $|a(x)|=|b(x)|$, that is, $a(x)=b(x)$ or $a(x)=-b(x)$. And possibly a different sign for different values of $x$, even though it doesn't happen here.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I just wanted the clean substitutions I did.Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Geometric interpretation:**

Rotate the right triangle. The projected length of the $\sqrt 2$ hypothenuses will vary following a sinusoid.

At the same time, this projected length is $\cos\theta+\sin\theta$.

[image]

Comment: Is $\theta$ in this case the angle between the yellow line on the right and the x-axis?

Comment: @NεoPλατo: yep. I hope the figure is self-explanatory.

Comment: @Allawonder: yep, on the figure you see both the $\sqrt2$ coefficient and the $45°$ phase-shift.

Comment: However, in the figure here you have rotated by $π/2$ instead of $π/4.$

Comment: @Allawonder: no, I have rotated the right triangle by an unknown angle. But it is a right isoceles triangle.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh, I see now. I had been rotating only the yellow radius before. Finally, for this to work, then the angle between the green line and the horizontal axis should be $\theta+\phi,$ isn't it? Yet clearly it is less than $\theta.$

Comment: @Allawonder: $\phi=-\pi/4$, but why do you worry ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I worry when I don't understand things. But I thought you said $\phi$ was an unknown angle?

Comment: @Allawonder: come on, forget these angles. Draw the right triangle with sides on the axis. Then rotate it freely while you project the hypothenuses to $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the cosine of angle difference formula,

$\sqrt2\cos\left(x-\dfrac\pi4\right)=\sqrt2\cos(x)\cos\left(\dfrac\pi4\right)+\sqrt2\sin(x)\sin\left(\dfrac\pi4\right)=\cos x+\sin x.$

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Indeed all linear combinations of the form $a\cos x+b\sin x$ are sinusoids, as shown below:

Write this as $$\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\left(a\cos x+b\sin x\right)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos x+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin x\right)=R(\sin\phi\cos x+\cos\phi\sin x)=R\sin(\phi+x),$$ where $R=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\tan\phi=a/b.$

In your case, you have $a=b=1,$ so that you have $$\sqrt 2\sin(π/4+x).$$

Comment: I thought that $\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\sin \phi$ going by the way you defined $\tan \phi$

Comment: @NεoPλατo Yes, but it's consistent with the trig formula $\sin(x+\phi)$ instead of $\cos(x-\phi)$. However, there is a flaw: by $\tan \phi=a/b$, in this precise context,
one really means $\phi=\mathrm{atan2}(a,b)$ (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)), i.e. the polar angle of the point $(b,a)$.
It's not equivalent in general. For instance, if both $a$ and $b$ are negative, it won't work.

Comment: For instance, with $a=-3,b=-2$, this answer will lead to $a\cos x+b\sin x=\sqrt{13}\sin(x+\arctan(3/2))$,
while it should be $a\cos x+b\sin x=\sqrt{13}\sin(x-\arctan(3/2)+\pi)$. There is no way to tell which is which with only $\tan\phi=3/2$.

Comment: @NεoPλατo Yes, that's it. Do you see something different?

Comment: @Allawonder Your answer is actually confusing come to think of it

Comment: @NεoPλατo How so? Where is the confusion?

Comment: Nevermind. I've seen the logic, thanks

Comment: @NεoPλατo Oh, LOL, I see now. One can always write a linear combination as a sinusoid -- that means either as a sine or cosine. Actually, a cosine is just a shifted sine. So, to get your result, subtract $π/2$ from the argument, that is you now have $$R\sin(\phi+x)=R\cos(\phi-π/2+x).$$ For your specific case you have $$\sqrt 2\sin(π/4+x)=\sqrt 2\cos(π/4-π/2+x)=\sqrt 2\cos(-π/4+x)=\sqrt 2\cos(x-π/4),$$ where the last equality follows because the cosine is even. That is, because $\cos(-y)=\cos y.$ Hopefully, the confusion has disappeared?

Comment: @Allawonder Yes, thanks a lot for the trig education